# Remove all Navigation Backstacks

Tags: android

I'm using new jetpack navigation library. Here I have 3 fragments A, B & C. A is my main fragment. From A fragment navigate to B fragment(A->B). From B to C(B->C). C->A then A->C->B->A->B like this. From whichever fragment I navigate if I press the system back button then I should navigate to A fragment Without having any backstacks pending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place fragment `A` as a start destination and then add them all as top level destinations. For that you would need an `AppBarConfiguration`:

```
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

//in onCreate or somewhere
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.fragmentA,
            R.id.fragmentB,
            R.id.fragmentC
        )
    )
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Comment: setOf is in kotlin. What to write in java?

Comment: you can add a static `Set<T>` variable I guess.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: I used this "Arrays.asList" working fine. Thank you for ur time :)